# MySQL after insert check the first 14 characters

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying something to check the barcodes from the parts, because of the risk of mixing.The barcodes is made up 24 characters, the first 14 characters is the part number as the last 10 characters is the counter, is it a solution to check the first 14 characters?

Here is an example of barcode: 308739420**D52**AD1702600131

Mixing parts is because next barcode that is from another part:
308739420**B0L**AD1702600131

Therefore, my question is: Can I check when entering the first 14 characters in the database?

I can say so show me the script that I use today for introducing barcodes in the database:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>insert data in database using mysqli</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="main">
    <h1>Barcode checker</h1>
        <div id="login"><hr/>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <label>Barcode :</label>
                <input type="text" name="TAK0010barcode" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Please enter barcode"/><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
 
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "barcode";
$password = "barcode";
$dbname = "barcode";
 
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO tak0010 (TAK0010barcode)
VALUES ('".$_POST["TAK0010barcode"]."')";
 
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<span style='color: green; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold'>SUCCES!!</span>";
} else {
    echo "<span style='color: red; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold'>EROARE!!</span>";
}
 
$conn->close();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: MySQL has a `substring()` function. Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: Do you want to check to see if the first 14 characters already exists in the database? If not, insert, if yes, do nothing?

Comment: I want to check if the first 14 characters of the bar code is the same (308739420D52AD) because if you inadvertently insert the barcode on the other part (308739420B0LAD) there is a risk of mixing parts.

Comment: is the same as what?

Comment: Same with a variable check, or something like. So I want every bar code that is introduced to check that the first 14 characters of the barcode (308739420D52AD1702600131) to be identical with "308739420D52AD".

Comment: In PHP? You would then need two variables to check, then use `substr()` limit the characters and then check for a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PHP function `substr()`:

```
$control = '308739420D52AD';
$test = substr($_POST["TAK0010barcode"], 0, strlen($control));

if($control == $test){

   $sql = "INSERT INTO tak0010 (TAK0010barcode)
           VALUES ('".$_POST["TAK0010barcode"]."')";
// etc...
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

**UPDATE:** Extended example, replace all within your php code with this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "barcode";
        $password = "barcode";
        $dbname = "barcode";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

    $control = '308739420D52AD'; // YOUR BAR CODE IDENTIFIER
    $test = substr($_POST["TAK0010barcode"], 0, strlen($control)); // BEGINNING OF THE POSTED BAR CODE.. SET TO SAME LENGTH AS BAR CODE IDENTIFIER

    if($control == $test){ // CHECK IF STRINGS ARE ALIKE

        $sql = "INSERT INTO tak0010 (TAK0010barcode)
                VALUES ('".$_POST["TAK0010barcode"]."')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "<span style='color: green; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold'>SUCCES!!</span>";
        } else {
            echo "<span style='color: red; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold'>EROARE!!</span>";
        }

        $conn->close();
    } else { // STRINGS DO NOT MATCH!
        echo "<span style='color: red; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold'>The barcode don't match the part number. Please use a barcode starting with ".$control."</span>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael K. I have been inserted into the php and i receiving this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\Sites\barcode\index.php on line 35". I read and on the PHP Manual, and not found anything to help me.

Comment: You have to close the IF condition with `}` later down after the sql execution.. My exempel shows just beginning of code...

Comment: Thank you for the full code, but the script not working, i don't know what the problem is... When entering the data in textbox and pressing the "Submit" button, the page reloaded, and do not insert in database anything, not appear the error message.

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in my code, it should be: `substr($_POST["TAK0010barcode"], 0, strlen($control)` where the zero indicates the start position. I have updated my answer accordingly... Let me know if it works four you now.

Comment: Thank you very much. The script works correctly. Thank you.